# Шрифт, цвет контента в блоках

Tags: css

В CSS не могу нустроить шрифт, цвет контента в блоках, даже не знаю какой код в CSS для этого нужно. http://cs-jumba.do.am/ - вот мой тестовый сайт, на котором я каждый день учусь верстать. Вёрсткой занимаюсь всего 1 день и могу прописать не много. Помогите мне, пожалуйста, прописать CSS код для контента в блоках =)

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Понимаите,в курсу ,которому я учился, небыло ткого урока! Был только урок по изменению цвета ссылок и то, он был по курсу html!

Comment: Не хочу вас огорчать, но вы смотрели курс не по css, а по html.

Comment: Согласен с Elime, если хотите можете добавить в скайп node_xaker. Я Вам детальнее объясню

Comment: Вы что? я же вам объяснил что непонял в ксс, а не в html, это разные вещи!

Comment: >на котором я каждый день учусь верстать.Вёрсткой занимаюсь всего 1 день

Оригинально =)

Comment: css.manual.ru вам поможет, это некая шпоргалка почти со всеми свойствами, почитайте)))

Comment: > Вы что? я же вам объяснил что непонял в ксс, а не в html, это разные вещи!

да ну, врешь

Comment: каждый день учусь верстать.Вёрсткой занимаюсь всего 1 день...

Это реально - "сказал как отрезал" xDDD

Comment: @AlexWindHope, не то слово, и придраться не к чему :D

Answer (score 2):

Если я Вас правильно понял Вам цвет шрифта и стиль его? Или заливка?
Если цвет то в нужный класс вставляем

```
.class{  
  color: red; - где red - это цвет.  
  font-family: Times new Roman; - где Times new Roman - сам стиль шрифта  
 }
```

Если Вы не знаете как прописать именно для индвида(отдельного блока, тогда для каждой теги html надо писать свой класс. Подробные могу объяснить если Вам надо.
Кстати если Вам интересно верстать предлагаю сохранить в закладках вот этот сайт [htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru)

Answer (score 1):

```
.your_css_class{
    color:#f00; //цвет в блоке your_css_class будет красным
}
```

А вообще вопрос немного неадекватен, такое впечатление что вы хотите что бы вам сейчас дали курс по css. В любом учебнике, статьях для новичков по css, рассматривается изменение шрифта, фона, и подобных элементарных вещах. Автор кури матчасть.